# How to make argsort return 2D indexes

Tags: sorting, indexing, pytorch, 2d

torch argsort returns indexes inside the row or a column depending on dim=...

How can I instead get a 2D indexes ..f.e..

```
[[ r1,r2,r3,...], [c1,c2,c3,.....]]
```

---

thanks... this is what I did

```
#https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/35674
def unravel_indices(indices, shape):
    coord = []

    for dim in reversed(shape):
        coord.append(torch.fmod(indices, dim))
        indices = torch.div(indices, dim, rounding_mode='floor')

    coord = torch.stack(coord[::-1], dim=-1)

    return coord
torch.unravel_indices = unravel_indices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `numpy` has `unravel_index` to perform this, there's no built-in for Torch but you can do it yourself. Easy enough for two dimensions:

```
yy, xx = indices // width, indices % width
```

fwiw pytorch has had a [function request and PR(s) floating around](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/35674) for several years now.